# How can I smooth out my CSS3 Animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have made a simple CSS3 animation, but it is extremely rough looking. It moves very jagged. Is there a way I can smooth out the animation and make it look a little more natural? I am attempting to make the Microsoft Cortona logo.

The HTML:

```
<div name="CortanaRing1" id="CortonaRing1" class="CortonaRing1">

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#CortonaRing1 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    border: 30px solid #000;
    animation-name: Cortona;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
}

@keyframes Cortona {
    0%  {
            border: 30px solid #000;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }

    25% {
            border: 25px solid #000;
            margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
        }

    50% {
           border: 30px solid #000;
           margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }
    100%{
           border: 25px solid #000;
           margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
        }
}
```

You can see a demo of my code working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/

Comment: I tried adding an image of what is should look like, but apparently I need 10 reputation. So sorry for no image.

Comment: Try using CSS transform (scale, perhaps) instead of border radius. Border radius and margins not have subpixel values, making transitions looking very rough.

Comment: I see what you saying Terry, but but how would I use 'scale' to adjust the border width from lets say 30px to 25px, because I just want the black ring to get wider and not the entire div.

Comment: Maybe perhaps I would use transition?

Comment: You could play with an inset `box-shadow` and the `padding`, that way you wouldn't have the _jumpy_ effect. Let me come up with a demo

Comment: What is animation effect ? Not appear to display animations at http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/ ?

Comment: It probably doesn't show up because it's not using the prefixes. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/3/ that has the `-webkit` prefix. Does it work?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yes. Added  `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;`
   , `-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;` for  "smooth out" effect See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function , http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/5/

Comment: Like Terry mentioned, CSS is a lot better at animating transforms than anything else. Have a look at this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZWugkJV5Ks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing, unless you want it that way in particular, you could eliminate the last step of the animation. That way the first state and the last state will be the same, avoiding the jump that you see when the animation ends:

```
@keyframes Cortona {
    0%  {
            border: 30px solid #000;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }

    50% {
            border: 25px solid #000;
            margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
        }

    100% {
           border: 30px solid #000;
           margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }
}
```

Then, as I mentioned in the comments, I would not use the `border` and `margin` because you get that "jumpy" effect on FF and IE (not on Chrome). You could use the `box-shadow` with an `inset` value. The advantage of using it is that the box doesn't move from its original position (avoiding that "relocation" that you get when changing the border/margin).

Something like this:

```
@keyframes Cortona {
    0%  {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 30px #000;
        }

    50% {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 25px #000;
        }

    100% {
           box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 30px #000;
        }
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/2/

Notice that the CSS would change slightly, as I added `padding:30px;` to `#CortonaRing1`.

---

The previous example makes the ring grow inward; if you want it to grow outward, remove the `inset` from the rule:

```
@keyframes Cortona {
    0%  {
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 1px 30px #000;
        }

    50% {
            box-shadow:  0px 0px 1px 25px #000;
        }

    100% {
           box-shadow:  0px 0px 1px 30px #000;
        }
}
```

See a demo working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gjvhsje6/4/ (in this case instead of playing with the `padding`, you may want to adjust the `margin`)

Comment: The smoothness of that is exactly what im looking for. But I wish the black ring to do the same thing, but only pulsate outward instead of inward. Because that is the outer ring of the logo. So I want it to stay the same size on the inside so I can have the smaller inner ring pulsate towards the center.

Comment: Thats kind of hard to work, does that make sense? And thanks a lots guys. You are helping me out a lot here.

Comment: If you want to make it grow to the outside, just remove the `inset`.

Comment: So if I could get this to work in the oposite direction it would be perfect

Comment: That is exactly what I want! THANK YOU! So 'inset' basically just means inward I guess. So just use normal box-shadow on the outer ring and inset on the inner ring and that will be perfect. But it still looks a little jumpy to me. If I add more percentages in the @keyframe and gradually change it do you think that would help a little, rather than going from 30 directly to 25?

Comment: I don't know about more percentages. I think something that would impact more positively in the animation would be to have "round" numbers. For example, the animation lasts for 4 seconds, and it changes by 5px (25 to 30, and viceversa). Maybe if it grew a multiple of 4 (e.g.: 8px 25 to 33) it would look smoother. Specially if you change the animation to linear (`animation-timing-function:linear;`) as they suggested above.